# Reactive coloring in DT table

Tags: shiny, dt

Need help. Below is the application. ColB is to be colored based on numbers in ColA. Below is the condition table

[image]

Just to brief : if ColB is 2, So it is lesser than 6 (12/2), it should be red and similarly for others. I tried to build the code myself and came up with below . But looks like there is some issue in the code . I have attached the output also below and the logic is not working properly.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

```{r}
tab1 <- data.frame(ColA = c(12,34,45,56), ColB = c(2,32,30,56))
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
DT::DTOutput("table1")
output$table1 <- DT::renderDT(
    datatable(tab1))
```
````

Below is the output I got 
[image]

So As per the code, the highlighted arrows are showing color.

First Arrow (Supposed to be red but it is showing as Yellow)
Second Arrow (Supposed to be Yellow but it is showing as Green)
Note : ColB is randomly generated and you may not see these numbers when you run it. But you observe randomly, this issue you will find for sure when you run as well. Not sure what is wrong in the code . Below is the code for your reference

Answer (score 0):

You could use `formatStyle` from `DT` ([link](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html)):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
```

```{r}
tab1 <- data.frame(ColA = c(12,34,45,56), ColB = c(2,32,30,56)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(backgroundColB = case_when(
    ColA==ColB ~ 1,
    ColA/2>ColB ~ -1,
    ColA/2<ColB ~ 0
  ))
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
DT::DTOutput("table1")
output$table1 <- DT::renderDT(
    datatable(tab1, options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=2)))) %>%
  formatStyle('ColB', "backgroundColB",
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(-.5,.5), c("red","yellow","green") ))
)
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I also tried . I have added to my question. But there is some issue in the code, though the logic is correct

Comment: Hi, I've rerun the script adding the rows you pointed out, and they were colored the way you wanted. I think you changed something of the script, without your exact code I can´t help you further.